# How to retrieve current month in SSRS expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I want to get current month as default value of a parameter.
I've come up with (which does not work):

```
=Month(Now())
```

Comment: I figured out I had wrong data type for a report parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get the month as an int that goes from 1 to 12, you can use this

```
SELECT MONTH(GETDATE())
```

This answer was based on the official documentation that you can see in here - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx

**Edit**

For reporting services specifically, you can use

```
MonthName(NOW())
```

This will return a month name and i believe is the function you're looking for.

Or, in case you want the month as an integer, try using

```
Month(TODAY())
```

Comment: Yeah, but instead of a month name in SSRS and I'd like to have a number, so I can use it further on my procedure.
=Name() should return an int.

Comment: @StanislavJirák Try using Month(TODAY() then and tell me if it worked.

Comment: I'm glad to know that i helped you. If you don't mind, please don't forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: MonthName accepts an integer rather than "Now()". You can instead do =MONTHNAME(MONTH(NOW())) to get the actual month name

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the month as an integer you can do what you had listed originally

```
=MONTH(NOW())
```

You can convert that from an integer to the actual month name by using

```
=MONTHNAME(MONTH(NOW()))
```